# Integrating out complex bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

From [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9705091), I'm trying to integrate out the massive fields of the $D0$ brane action, expanded around a classical background. I have a ghost action with complex fields:

$$S_{GH} = i \int d\tau \overline{c}_{1} (- \partial_{\tau}^{2} + r^{2}) c_{1} + \overline{c}_{2} (- \partial_{\tau}^{2} + r^{2}) c_{2} - \overline{c}_{3}  \partial_{\tau}^{2} c_{3} + \sqrt{g}\epsilon^{abc}(\partial_{\tau} \overline{c}^{a})   c^{b} A^{c} - \sqrt{g}\epsilon^{a3x} \epsilon^{cbx} B^{i}_{3} \overline{c}^{a} c^{b} Y^{i}_{c} $$

I know that there are two bosons with $m^{2} = r^{2}$ and one boson with $m^{2} = 0$. My question is: how do I get the determinant when the fields $c_{1}, c_{2}$ and their complex conjugates are integrated out, given that the terms are not in the simple form $\phi (-\partial_{\tau}^{2} + m^{2}) \phi$?

Comment: [Related posts on arXiv:hep-th/9705091 by OP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A92665+url%3A%22*9705091*%22).

Comment: If $r^2$ is not a constant, this is an intractable problem.

Comment: @mike stone $r^2 = b^2 + (v \tau)^2 $ where $b$ is the impact parameter but the determinants are still given in terms of $r^2$ and the answer looks pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed that it was one dimensional!  For a general operator  $-\partial_t^2+V(t)$ one can use the shooting method to relate $\det[-\partial_t^2+V(t)]$ with boundary conditions $\psi(0)=0=\psi(L)$to the corresponding Schroedinger equation: If
$$
(-\partial_t^2+V(t))\psi(t)=\lambda \psi(t)
$$
with initial conditions
$\psi(0)=0$,  $\psi'(0)=1$, then
$$  
\frac{\det[-\partial_t^2+V_1(t)]}{\det[-\partial_t^2+V_2(t)]}=  \frac{\psi_1(L)}{\psi_2(L)}.
$$

Similarly one can relate $\det[-\partial_t^2+V(t)]$ on the whole real line to the transmision  coefficient $T(\lambda)$.

In the paper they just have a harmonic oscillator so everything boils down to Mehler's formula [eq (3.2) in your paper].

Comment: I don’t have a problem with evaluating the determinant. It’s just the power of the determinant that I can’t figure out. Is this similar to the integration $\int dz d\bar{z} \exp(z a \bar{z}) = \frac{\pi}{a}?$

Comment: Yes. Since you have $\bar c$ and $c$ you get $\det^{-1}$ rather than $\det^{-1/2}$ as you would if $c$ were real.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've worked the whole thing out
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540887/integrating-massive-modes-for-supergraviton-d0-brane-scattering